# Syntax error in UPDATE statement OleDb Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I check my SQL Statement many times and it seems that my SQL Statement is Error. I don't why it doesn't work. My SQL Statement is correct and It resulted to this OleDBException "Syntax error in UPDATE statement.".

Here is the code

```
   OleDbConnection CN = new OleDbConnection(mysql.CON.ConnectionString);
   CN.Open();
   cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Update Mosque Set Name='" + txtNAME.Text + "', No='" + Convert.ToInt32(txtNO.Text) + "', place='" + txtPlace.Text + "', group='" + txtGroup.Text + "', description='" + txtdec.Text + "' where  id='" + txtID.Text + "'", CN);
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   CN.Close();
```

need help please to know what is the error here

Comment: How does the update statement looks like? Can you break it. I advise to store the query first into a string variable. Make debugging more easy.

Comment: @user2746526 Please save your cmd1 to a string varialbe and print it out for us to see the final result.

Comment: You really need to check what the string value of `txtName.Text` is before placing it in the query.  You are extremely prone to a SQL Injection by placing the variable directly into the query.  This is a major vulnerability and bound to cause your queries to fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what database are you using, but I am sure that GROUP is a reserved keyword in practically any existant SQL database. This word cannot be used without some kind of delimiter around it. The exact kind of delimiter depend on the database kind. What database are you using?

Said that, please do not use string concatenation to build sql commands, but use always a parameterized query. This will allow you to remove any possibilities of [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and avoid any syntax error if one or more of your input string contains a single quote somewhere

So, supposing you are using a MS Access Database (In Access also the word NO is a reserved keyword and the delimiters for reserved keywords are the square brakets) you could write something like this

```
string commandText = "Update Mosque Set Name=?, [No]=?, place=?, " + 
                     "[Group]=?, description=? where  id=?"
using(OleDbConnection CN = new OleDbConnection(mysql.CON.ConnectionString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(commandText, CN))
{
    CN.Open();
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",txtNAME.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",Convert.ToInt32(txtNO.Text));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",txtPlace.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4",txtGroup.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5",txtdec.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6",txtID.Text);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Instead for MySQL you have to use the backticks around the GROUP keyword

```
string commandText = "Update Mosque Set Name=?, No=?, place=?, " + 
                     "`Group`=?, description=? where  id=?"
```

Comment: Steve,if i insert a null value i got error "input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: Where do you insert a null value? You could post a new question copying or referencing this one and explaining what is the problem. (More people will see your new question and you will get a response quickly)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without knowing the values of the texboxes, but I suspect that one of them has an apostrophe which is causing an invalid syntax.

I recommend using parameters instead:

```
   cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Update Mosque Set [Name]=@Name, [No]=@No, [place]=@Place, [group]=@Group, [description]=@Description WHERE id=@ID", CN);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtNAME.Text);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No",Convert.ToInt32(txtNO.Text));
   // etc.
```